# polymer paper-scroll-header-panel doesn't display

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am writing a polymer website and just recently decided that the architecture of my site would be better if I moved my main logic out of `index.html` and into a web component. For some reason, in the web component when I use `paper-scroll-header-panel`, nothing displays. When I comment out the import for it, things start displaying again. Everything worked as expected when everything was originally in `index.html`.

I don't understand why it won't work now. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

new `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <title>Joyce K. Lee</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link rel="import" href="styles/app-theme.html">
  <link rel="import" href="styles/shared-styles.html">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="elements/app.html">

  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <joyce-app></joyce-app>
  </template>

  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

new `app.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- Iron elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

<!-- Paper elements -->
<!-- <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html"> -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">

<!-- Neon elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">

<!-- Firebase -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/firebase-element/firebase-auth.html">

<!-- Routing -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">

<link rel="import" href="custom-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="blog.html">
<link rel="import" href="artist.html">
<link rel="import" href="teacher.html">
<link rel="import" href="research.html">
<link rel="import" href="contact.html">
<link rel="import" href="login.html">
<link rel="import" href="simple-overlay.html">

<dom-module id="joyce-app">
  <template>
    <style>

    </style>

    <app-router style="display:none;">
      <app-route path="/" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/artist" import="/elements/artist.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/teacher" import="/elements/teacher.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/research" import="/elements/research.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/contact" import="/elements/contact.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="*" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
    </app-router>

    <!-- Main Area -->
    <paper-scroll-header-panel fixed>
      <!-- Main Toolbar -->
      <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">

        <div class="middle">
          <div class="app-name">Joyce K. Lee</div>
          <span class="flex"></span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" onclick="login.open()" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-square" onclick="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <template if="{{user}}">{{user.password.username}}</template>
        </div>

        <!-- Application sub title -->
        <div class="bottom-title">
          <paper-tabs id="nav" selected="{{selected}}">
                <paper-tab><a href="#/"><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                <paper-tab><a href="#/artist"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:brush"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                <paper-tab><a href="#/teacher"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:apple"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                <paper-tab><a href="#/research"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:book"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                <paper-tab><a href="#/contact"><iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="content">
        <neon-animated-pages style="height:100%" id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
          <neon-animatable><joyce-blog></joyce-blog></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-artist></joyce-artist></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-teacher></joyce-teacher></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-research></joyce-research></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-contact></joyce-contact></neon-animatable>
        </neon-animated-pages>
      </div>

      <simple-overlay id="login" with-backdrop>
        <joyce-login></joyce-login>
      </simple-overlay>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'joyce-app'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

original `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Joyce K. Lee">
  <title>Joyce K. Lee</title>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the `app/` directory -->

  <!-- Chrome for Android theme color -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#00bcd4">

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00bcd4">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- will be replaced with elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
  <!-- endreplace-->

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <app-router style="display:none;">
      <app-route path="/" import="/elements/joyce-blog.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/artist" import="/elements/joyce-artist.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/teacher" import="/elements/joyce-teacher.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/research" import="/elements/joyce-research.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="/contact" import="/elements/joyce-contact.html"></app-route>
      <app-route path="*" import="/elements/joyce-blog.html"></app-route>
    </app-router>

    <!-- Main Area -->
    <paper-scroll-header-panel main condenses keep-condensed-header>
      <!-- Main Toolbar -->
      <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="medium-tall">

      <div class="center horizontal layout fit">
          <div class="app-name">Joyce K. Lee</div>
          <span class="flex"></span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" onclick="login.open()" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-square" onclick="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <template if="{{user}}">{{user.password.username}}</template>
        </div>

        <!-- Application sub title -->
        <div class="bottom bottom-container center layout flex fit">
          <div class="bottom-title paper-font-subhead">
            <paper-tabs id="nav" selected="{{selected}}">
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/"><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/artist"><iron-icon icon="image:brush"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/teacher"><iron-icon icon="maps:place"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/research"><iron-icon icon="work"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/contact"><iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="content">
        <neon-animated-pages style="height:100%" id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
          <neon-animatable><joyce-blog></joyce-blog></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-artist></joyce-artist></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-teacher></joyce-teacher></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-research></joyce-research></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-contact></joyce-contact></neon-animatable>
        </neon-animated-pages>
      </div>

      <simple-overlay id="login" with-backdrop>
        <joyce-login></joyce-login>
      </simple-overlay>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>

    <!-- Uncomment next block to enable Service Worker support (1/2) -->
    <paper-toast id="caching-complete" duration="6000" text="Caching complete! This app will work offline."></paper-toast>
  </template>

  <script>
    var scope = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
    scope.selected = 0;
  </script>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you given a height to `paper-scroll-header-panel` parent in your CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out! It looks like my styling from my `app-theme.html` was only applying to `index.html`, so it wasn't getting applied to my custom element.

Apparently the correct way to do this is to also have your theme in a `.css` file and import it into each custom element that you want to use that theme.